# Changing the SVG color in CSS

Tags: css, svg, optimization, seo, fill

I want to change the svg icon color in css, but it won't change for some reason. Please, help :
https://codepen.io/Flowersj/pen/OJExzME

I tried adding class to parent tag and trying to style it, didn't work.

HTML:
`<svg class="navigation-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/><path d="M18.031 16.617l4.283 4.282-1.415 1.415-4.282-4.283A8.96 8.96 0 0 1 11 20c-4.968 0-9-4.032-9-9s4.032-9 9-9 9 4.032 9 9a8.96 8.96 0 0 1-1.969 5.617zm-2.006-.742A6.977 6.977 0 0 0 18 11c0-3.868-3.133-7-7-7-3.868 0-7 3.132-7 7 0 3.867 3.132 7 7 7a6.977 6.977 0 0 0 4.875-1.975l.15-.15z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,1)"/></svg>`

CSS:
`.navigation-icon { fill: red; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class needs to be assigned to the path, not the svg container.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.nav-icon-path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16">
        <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
        <path class="nav-icon-path" d="M18.031 16.617l4.283 4.282-1.415 1.415-4.282-4.283A8.96 8.96 0 0 1 11 20c-4.968 0-9-4.032-9-9s4.032-9 9-9 9 4.032 9 9a8.96 8.96 0 0 1-1.969 5.617zm-2.006-.742A6.977 6.977 0 0 0 18 11c0-3.868-3.133-7-7-7-3.868 0-7 3.132-7 7 0 3.867 3.132 7 7 7a6.977 6.977 0 0 0 4.875-1.975l.15-.15z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,1)"/>
    </svg>
</body>
```

You can still put a class on the svg container and even use it for hover:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.navigation-icon > .nav_icon_path {
  fill: red;
}
.navigation-icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation-icon:hover > .nav_icon_path {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <svg class="navigation-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16">
        <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
        <path class="nav_icon_path" d="M18.031 16.617l4.283 4.282-1.415 1.415-4.282-4.283A8.96 8.96 0 0 1 11 20c-4.968 0-9-4.032-9-9s4.032-9 9-9 9 4.032 9 9a8.96 8.96 0 0 1-1.969 5.617zm-2.006-.742A6.977 6.977 0 0 0 18 11c0-3.868-3.133-7-7-7-3.868 0-7 3.132-7 7 0 3.867 3.132 7 7 7a6.977 6.977 0 0 0 4.875-1.975l.15-.15z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,1)"/>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked! The only question, if I ever want to add a hover for it (without empty spaces, because svg has transparent areas), should I create a different class for a parent element (<a class =‘navigation-icon-wrapper> for example) and do it so:
.navigation-icon-wrapper:hover .navigation-icon {}
or I can use the same ‘navigation-icon’ for both path and the parent and just refer to the path so:
.navigation-icon a:hover .navigation-icon {}

?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a hover example. No need to wrap it for the hover effect... now, we can use that svg container.

Comment: You can still wrap it if you want and follow the same child selector pattern in css.

Answer (score 2):

AtomicUs is right, you need to target your path instead of the svg element because the svg element doesn't have a fill property. In this specific svg you can also remove the empty path as it's redundant and then target the path child of the parent navigation-icon svg:

```css
.navigation-icon path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="navigation-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16">
    <path d="M18.031 16.617l4.283 4.282-1.415 1.415-4.282-4.283A8.96 8.96 0 0 1 11 20c-4.968 0-9-4.032-9-9s4.032-9 9-9 9 4.032 9 9a8.96 8.96 0 0 1-1.969 5.617zm-2.006-.742A6.977 6.977 0 0 0 18 11c0-3.868-3.133-7-7-7-3.868 0-7 3.132-7 7 0 3.867 3.132 7 7 7a6.977 6.977 0 0 0 4.875-1.975l.15-.15z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,1)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Would be great if I could use a parent class <div class=‘navigation-icon-wrapper’> and just do it so:

.navigation-icon-wrapper path {} 

But I tried it and it won’t react on ‘path’ at all. In this case I can only do:
 .navigation-icon-wrapper .navigation-icon {}

Comment: If you add svg into the css path like .navigation-icon-wrapper svg path {} you're able to, but I'd recommend against making css changes from that far away. It limits you and you get caught painting yourself into a corner :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fill="currentColor"` on the path and then you can style the svg using the `color` property:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg class="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16">
    <path d="M18.031 16.617l4.283 4.282-1.415 1.415-4.282-4.283A8.96 8.96 0 0 1 11 20c-4.968 0-9-4.032-9-9s4.032-9 9-9 9 4.032 9 9a8.96 8.96 0 0 1-1.969 5.617zm-2.006-.742A6.977 6.977 0 0 0 18 11c0-3.868-3.133-7-7-7-3.868 0-7 3.132-7 7 0 3.867 3.132 7 7 7a6.977 6.977 0 0 0 4.875-1.975l.15-.15z" fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>
<svg class="blue" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16">
    <path d="M18.031 16.617l4.283 4.282-1.415 1.415-4.282-4.283A8.96 8.96 0 0 1 11 20c-4.968 0-9-4.032-9-9s4.032-9 9-9 9 4.032 9 9a8.96 8.96 0 0 1-1.969 5.617zm-2.006-.742A6.977 6.977 0 0 0 18 11c0-3.868-3.133-7-7-7-3.868 0-7 3.132-7 7 0 3.867 3.132 7 7 7a6.977 6.977 0 0 0 4.875-1.975l.15-.15z" fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>
```